# using curly double brackets inside another curly double brackets in django template

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I started studying Django few days back, while doing a project I came across a situation.
In the views.py, I'm passing

```
def chat_rooms(request):
context = dict()
context['title'] = 'Chat'
rooms = Chat_rooms.objects.filter(Q(user1 = request.user.id) | Q(user2 = request.user.id) )
context['rooms'] = rooms
for room in rooms:
    rmssg = Chats.objects.filter(room_id = room.id)
    lmssg = Chats.objects.latest('id')
    context[str(room.id)] = lmssg
return render(request,'previlageGroup/chat_rooms.html',context)
```

In the Django template,chat_room.html

```
{% for room in rooms %}
<div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
<a href="{% url 'pgroup:chat.screen' room.id %}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">
            {{ {{room.id}}.message}}
        </p>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
 {% endfor %}
```

In models.py

```
class Chat_rooms(models.Model):
user1 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user1')  
user2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user2')
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Chats(models.Model):
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
has_viewed = models.BooleanField(default= False) 
message = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')  
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='receiver')
room = models.ForeignKey(Chat_rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Django is giving me a error, that `{{ {{room.id}}.message }}` is not possible.
How can I do this? Is there any other way?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the day, a django `Model` object is just like any other `object` in python, so you could easily do:

```
for room in rooms:
    rmssg = Chats.objects.filter(room_id = room.id)
    lmssg = Chats.objects.latest('id')
    room.last_msg = lmssg
```

And access `{{ room.last_msg }}` in your template. This might cause errors if you ever happen to implement a `last_msg` field though.

Perhaps a more elegant solution would be implementing a `related_name` to your `room` field. If you change the last line of your `views.py` to:

```
room = models.ForeignKey(Chat_rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="chats")
```

You would be able to do things like:

`room.chats.all() #get all messages from a chatroom`

And, in your templates, you could do:

```
{{ room.chats.last }}
```

To get the last message in the chat.